# Cannot make the UITableView show the content in object - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm learning Objective C, I'm totally new in this language and now I'm stuck with a UITableView.
I'm reading a ebook but what they write in the book are little different with the current Xcode version. I have tried to modify by myself for a day but still have no clue.

Here is my Object for My Book Store.

```
#import "Bookstore.h"
@implementation Bookstore
@synthesize myBookStore;

- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.myBookStore = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        Book *newBook = [[Book alloc] init];
        newBook.title = @"Objective C for Absolute Beginner";
        newBook.author = @"Bennett, Fisher and Lees";
        newBook.desc = @"iOS programming made easy";
        [self.myBookStore addObject:newBook];

        newBook = [[Book alloc] init];
        newBook.title = @"A Farewell To Arms";
        newBook.author = @"Ernest Hemingway";
        newBook.desc = @"The story of an affair between an English "
        "nurse and an American soldier "
        "on the Italian front "
        "during World War I.";
        [self.myBookStore addObject:newBook];
    }

    return self;

}
- (NSUInteger)count{
    return myBookStore.count;
}
- (Book *)bookAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{
    return [myBookStore objectAtIndex:index];
}
@end
```

And here is code in MasterViewController.m which I have tried to modify
Firstly I init my object as the tutorial in my ebook.

```
#import "LKMasterViewController.h"
#import "Bookstore.h"
#import "Book.h"
#import "LKDetailViewController.h"

@interface LKMasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
}
@end

@implementation LKMasterViewController

@synthesize myBookStore;

// INIT MY BOOK OBJECT //
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
        self.myBookStore = [[Bookstore alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
// END INIT //
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}

Then I modify in my UITableView

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return myBookStore.count; // THIS IS A NUMBER OF ROW IN SECTION, IT'S EQUAL TO NUMBER OF OBJECT IN OUR ARRAY
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

//    NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];  // THIS'S DEFAULT BUT I COMMENT IT
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.myBookStore bookAtIndex:indexPath.row].title;  // THIS IS WHERE I MODIFIED 
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}
```

Please help me, I know this may be a foolish question but I cant solve it by myself >"<, and it seem my ebook is out of date :(
I forgot to mention that there is not exception, no issue or errors when I run this app, the only thing is there is no thing in master view is shown up. >"<

NOTE: I put my source code at here: http://wikisend.com/download/793354/myBookStore.zip
I hope you guy can help me :(

Comment: do you want to display content stored in book object in UITableView?

Comment: are your delegates called, put some nslog in numberOfRows and cellForRow..

Comment: Unless your `LKMasterViewController` class inherits from `UITableViewController` (doesn't look like it, judging from the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method), you've probably just forgotten to set the table view's `delegate` and `dataSource`. Your book should mention how to do that somewhere, even if it's outdated.

Comment: As @omz says you need to ensure that the `UITableView` has your class as the `delegate` and `datasource`.  Also in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you are dequeuing a cell using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`, have you registered a Nib or class with this identifier using either `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`?

Comment: @omz: Yes I think I'm missing to declare somethings such as the method initWithName, in my ebook they don't mention anything about this, I have read it again and again for a day >"<. No datasource or delegate. Can you help me to solve it, or tell me how to solve this problem :( Here is my source code, thank for your help so so much http://wikisend.com/download/793354/myBookStore.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at your project, the problem seems to be that you're using a storyboard (which probably didn't exist when your book was written). Storyboards will not instantiate view controllers with the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method, but rather with `initWithCoder:`, so your `myBookstore` property is never initialized (so that you always get `0` for the number of books).

Replace the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method with something like this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.myBookStore = [[Bookstore alloc] init];
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
    }
    return self;
}
```

You'll run into some other problems because in your table view methods, you're sometimes using `myBookstore` and sometimes `_objects`, but this should get you over the first bump.

Comment: Thank you so so much, that is what I want to know, I know in my ebook they don't have storyboard but I tried to manage from the beginning of their example. Your help is really useful even I don't understand deeply initWithCoder method. I will try it right now. I'm very sorry because I cannot vote for you, I don't have enough reputation to vote right now, but I will comeback and vote it later. Thank you. :)